# Good resources for learning Croatian?

Tags: resource-request, slavic-languages

I've been looking for years for a good, comprehensive guide to learning Croatian that can take me through all the basic steps and get me started in speaking with my mother in her native tongue. Does anyone know of a good source for this?

What I am looking for is something similar to DuoLingo, where I will be able to break down sentences, understand every part and practice the language a bit with questions and explanations behind the grammatical rules. I also ask for **only Croatian** and not Serbo-Croatian, since it's a bit different from her dialect and it will be hard enough as it is speaking to her without the different terms for things.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have found anything that you ended up using? If yes, it would be nice if you could write this up in an answer to your question.

Answer (score 8):

The website [Easy Croatian](http://www.easy-croatian.com/) has 90 lessons (plus appendices) available for free (and for download) and seems very comprehensive - extensive & detailed lessons, and well-organized. However, it's not interactive like Duolingo is - [easy-croatian.com](http://www.easy-croatian.com/) is essentially a book.

Pimsleur also offers an [audio course for Croatian](http://www.pimsleur.com/learn-croatian), however, Pimsleur's method may not work as well for you as it does for some others. It's a 100% audio course, so if you're a visual learner, prefer charts & lists, it might not be the best option for you.

Finally, I'd recommend finding a real-life tutor, whether in-person or online. Two of the most popular language exchange websites are [italki](https://www.italki.com/teachers) (has a few Croatian teachers) and [Speaky](https://www.speaky.com/) (I couldn't find a number, but Croatian is on their list).

There's also the [Croatian subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/croatian/) (which seems dead) and the [Croatia subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/croatia/) (more active, you might be able to find a language exchange partner there). You could try asking either of those subreddits for a textbook recommendation.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Though this is not a book but there is an American YouTuber that's living in Croatia and she often makes videos about her life there in Croatian: [Kaleigh Hendershot - This Croatian Life](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_k8snbkwzqpxSIq5DUZYbw).

I would suggest you to watch cartoons like Peppa pig, just to get a "feeling" of how it sounds

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you trying Ling app(monkey logo). I think it would help you a lot, and I see that there also have Croatian, not sure how many languages there have, but I could say there have many many languages. I think this app is similar to Duolingo but more excellent than that because there have many features such as a speaking game so that you can be the native speaker from there or chatbot function. So there are beginners to advanced levels, which is a perfect one. So I hope this can help you.